# Extracting substring in cloud functions

Tags: python, regex, google-cloud-functions

I am uploading csv files stored in google cloud storage into bigquery tables.

this is some part of my function:

```
def upload_to_bq_from_gcs(event, context):
    filename = event['name']
    input_bucket = event['bucket']
    output_bucket = "sales_2020"
```

file names in the bucket are in this format:

```
confidential.SM4.B564.2022-01-07.CSV
public.SM4.B564.2022-01-07.CSV
confidential.test_result_1.B564.2022-01-07.CSV
public.test_result_1.B564.2022-01-07.CSV
```

fist par: first bit before first dot is confidential or public.
second part: between first and second dot is a combination or letters, numbers and underscore

I need to upload the data into confidential and public datasets. Table names will be second part of filename (anything from first to second dot)

I need to generate first and second part from filename.

```
second-part = filename.split('.')[1].split('.')[0]
```

I am wondering how I can first part(from first character until first dot)?

and also how I can replace "_" with "-" in the second part?

Answer (score 1):

The below code will generate the first and second parts:

```
m = str(filename).split('.', 2)[0]
k = str(filename).split('.', 2)[1]


print("first bit is : " ,m)
print("second bit is : " ,k)
```

For example if the filename is **confidential.SM4.B564.2022-01-07.CSV**
Output is:

```
first bit is : confidential
second bit is : SM4
```